# Developer options in Android 6.0 and 7.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat, developer-options

The developer options of Android Nougat are the same of Android Marshmallow? Or are there new options?

Comment: It depends on the maker, alsoif your using custom ROM or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available options doesn't strictly depend on Android displayed version and will vary by installed systems.

The source of the system is the changing factor.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make an exact comparison between the developer options of both Android versions. But as far as I can see by just looking at them on my phones (Stock, Android 6-7), they look exactly the same.